# resizing an exFAT partition on Windows 10

Tags: windows, exfat

I'm trying to shrink the main partition on my 2TB drive to 1TB, so that I can create a new one for installing a Linux distro. The Windows 10 disk manager doesn't let me shrink it, and I want to know if there's any alternatives to just removing it and making a new one.

Comment: Have you enabled dynamic disks or any other Microsoft proprietary technology?

Comment: @AndrewMorton that's for NTFS. Disk management can't resize exFAT partitions